# xlsxwriter / How do I fill all blank cells with a space (' ')?

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, xlsx, xlsxwriter

So, I want to do this for styling: to prevent text overspilling, without doing a text wrap.

I'm not sure even where to start with this one. I know there's a {'type':'blank'} attribute you can use... but I'm not sure what to do with it.

My code so far is below.

```
def export_to_xlsx(date):
    global df
    ## CREATE PD DATAFRAME
    all_mp_dict = scraper(date)
    df = pd.DataFrame(all_mp_dict)

    ## WORKSHEET FORMATTING
    workbook_loc = './mp_excel/mp_data_'+date+'.xlsx'
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(workbook_loc, engine='xlsxwriter')
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=date+'_raw')

    workbook = writer.book
    worksheet = writer.sheets[date+'_raw']

    header_format = workbook.add_format({
        'bold': True,
        'text_wrap': True,
        'valign': 'top',
        'fg_color': '#FFFF00',
        'border': 1})

    for col_num, value in enumerate(df.columns.values):
        worksheet.write(0, col_num+1, value, header_format)

    ## TO_EXCEL
    writer.close()
```

Comment: have you tried `df = df.fillna(' ')` before `df.to_excel`?

Comment: I wanted to keep the values as NaN in the dataframe, so I can use it later... but on reflection this might be the best approach. I could just create a new copy of the dataframe. Thank you.

Comment: `fillna()` doesn't work in place, so you can do `df.fillna(' ').to_excel()` and continue working with `df`

Comment: Worked great, thank you.